# Not able to split chararray field containing spaces and tabs between the words. Help me with the command using Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

### Sample.txt File

```
2017-01-01 10:21:59 THURSDAY    -39 3 Pick up a bus - Travel for two hours
2017-02-01 12:45:19 FRIDAY  -55 8 Pick up a train - Travel for one hour
2017-03-01 11:35:49 SUNDAY  -55 8 Pick up a train - Travel for one hour
I
.
.
```

When I executed the suggested command, it got split into three fields.

when I do the below operation, it is not working as expected.

```
A = LOAD 'Sample.txt' USING PigStorage() as (line:chararray);
B = foreach A generate STRSPLIT(line, ' ', 3);
c = foreach B generate $2;
split C into buslog if $0 matches '.*bus*.', trainlog if $0 matches '.*train*.';
```

Note:- Dump of C will give below result.

```
THURSDAY    -39 3 Pick up a bus - Travel for two hours
FRIDAY  -55 8 Pick up a train - Travel for one hour
SUNDAY  -55 8 Pick up a train - Travel for one hour
```

Requirement: In the above result, i want to split train and bus into two relations, but it is not happening as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is `.*string.*`.Notice that it is `.*` on both sides of the string.

```
split C into buslog if $0 matches '.*bus.*', trainlog if $0 matches '.*train.*';
```

Comment: - I tried the same, but it is not working. In our example, there is a tab space between the THURSDAY and the next word. (-39) If the delimiter is space, the above given command is working fine.

Comment: - You gave answers for the 4 queries which i raised. I am really happy for the answers that you gave for the previous queries. I tried with the query that you gave , but it is not working because the words are separated with space till THURSDAY and after that it is separated with tab and remaining words after 39 are separated with space again.

Comment: Replace the tabs with space and then split.STRSPLIT(REPLACE(line,'\\t',' '), ' ', 3);. Please upvote/mark as answer so that question is closed. People take time out of their lives to answer questions and the least you can do is mark it as answer if it solves your problem.If you hover over 0 with upvote/downvote signs, you should see a check mark and clicking on it will ensure that the answer is accepted.

Comment: - Actually, i am new to this. I don't know that i have to mark if the answer is right. I have to do some research on this. Anyway thanks for all the answers that you gave and working fine for me.