# Not able to split chararray field containing spaces and tabs between the words. Help command using Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

### My Sample.txt File

- 2017-01-01 10:21:59 THURSDAY -39 3 Pick up a bus - Travel for two hours
- 2017-02-01 12:45:19 FRIDAY -55 8 Pick up a train - Travel for one hour
- 2017-03-01 11:35:49 SUNDAY -55 8 Pick up a train - Travel for one hour
  .
  .
- when i do the below operation, it is not working as expected.
- A = LOAD 'Sample.txt' USING PigStorage() as (line:chararray);
- B = foreach A generate STRSPLIT(line, ' ', 3);
- C = foreach B generate $2;
- Note:- Dump of C will give below result.
- THURSDAY -39 3 Pick up a bus - Travel for two hours
- FRIDAY -55 8 Pick up a train - Travel for one hour
- SUNDAY -55 8 Pick up a train - Travel for one hour
- split C into buslog if $0 matches '.bus.', trainlog if $0 matches '.train.'; (Which is not working as per command. It is not generating the logs correctly.)
- Requirement: In the above result, i want to split train and bus into two relations, but it is not happening as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to split chararray field containing spaces and tabs between the words. Help me with the command using Apache Pig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071395/not-able-to-split-chararray-field-containing-spaces-and-tabs-between-the-words)

Comment: Yes. This ia a duplicate one.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
A = load 'Data' USING PigStorage() as (line:chararray);
B = foreach A generate STRSPLIT(line, ' ', 3);
C = foreach B generate flatten($0);
bus = filter C by ($2 matches '.*bus.*');
train = filter C by ($2 matches '.*train.*');
```